# postgresSQL How to do a SELECT clause with an condition iterating through a range of values?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

Hy everyone. This is my first post on Stack Overflow so sorry if it is clumpsy in any way.

I work in Python and make postgresSQL requests to a google BigQuery database. The data structure looks like this :

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNRUE.png)

where time is represented in nanoseconds, and **is not regularly spaced** (it is captured real-time).

What I want to do is to select, say, the mean price over a minute, for each minute in a time range that i would like to give as a parameter.
This time range is currently a list of timestamps that I build externally, and I make sure they are separated by one minute each :

```
[1606170420000000000, 1606170360000000000, 1606170300000000000, 1606170240000000000, 1606170180000000000, ...]
```

My question is : how can I extract this list of mean prices given that list of time intervals ?

Ideally I'd expect something like

```
SELECT AVG(price) OVER( PARTITION BY (time BETWEEN time_intervals[i] AND time_intervals[i+1] for i in range(len(time_intervals))) ) 
FROM table_name
```

but I know that doesn't make sense...

My temporary solution is to aggregate many SELECT ... UNION DISTINCT clauses, one for each minute interval. But as you can imagine, this is not very efficient... (I need up to 60*24 = 1440 samples)

Now there very well may already be an answer to that question, but since I'm not even sure about how to formulate it, I found nothing yet. Every link and/or tip would be of great help.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your sample data appears to be at millisecond resolution, and you are looking for averages at minute (sixty-second) resolution.

Please try this:

```
select div(time, 60000000000) as minute,
       pair,
       avg(price) as avg_price
  from your_table
 group by div(time, 60000000000) as minute, pair
```

If you want to control the intervals as you said in your comment, then please try something like this (I do not have access to BigQuery):

```
with time_ivals as (
  select tick, 
         lead(tick) over (order by tick) as next_tick
    from unnest(
           [1606170420000000000, 1606170360000000000, 
            1606170300000000000, 1606170240000000000, 
            1606170180000000000, ...]) as tick
)
select t.tick, y.pair, avg(y.price) as avg_price
  from time_ivals t
       join your_table y
         on y.time >= t.tick
        and y.time < t.next_tick
 group by t.tick, y.pair;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This solves my problem. Although I wanted to control precisely the limit of each interval I will make do with this.

Comment: PS: my time is actually in nanoseconds ; it is the time from the Unix epoch. But that hardly matters. Thanks again

Comment: @SifoDyas  Please see the update to my answer for how to control the actual intervals.

Comment: Yes thank you. I got something similar thinking it through. But I also realised I don't need this level of precision, and the first solution works perfectly.